# How to automatically disable "Allow computer to turn off this device" on all devices in Device Manager

Tags: powershell, batch-file, power-management, vbscript, device-manager

I need to frequently go through most devices and disable this option (if the Power Management tab is available) for clients machines (Win10/11).

Don't mind how it's done, Powershell/batch/VBS/etc.

I have just been checking out [powercfg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options), didn't see a command line option that deals with this in particular.

EDIT: What would also be useful is to generate a list of devices that have this setting enabled.

Comment: Why try and script this? This is why GPOs exist, for a domain-joined system and local GPO for a workgroup system.

Comment: @Nathan - You might look over and test with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon. I know it can disable devices and even with remote command because I'm done it before with Windows 10 machines. It states that is also configures in conjunction with "disabling" so that may help you for another potential starting point.